# Include css and/or script from template tag

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-templates

I have a Django app that uses a template tag to process a wordpress style shortcode. My code is based on https://github.com/emilbjorklund/django-template-shortcodes/blob/master/shortcodes but I have added my own parser.  The shortcode is basically an image album e.g. [album view=slideshow id=1], where the view can either be a slideshow (Bootstrap Carousel) or Gallery (Lightbox).   My parser looks like:

```
def parse(tag_atts, tag_contents=None):
    #Check our id is a digit.
    tag_atts['content'] = "Album Short Tag Error"
    if tag_atts['id'].isdigit:
        #try:

        # Get the data from the album
        album = Album.objects.get(pk = tag_atts['id'] )#.select_related()
        images = Image.objects.filter(album__id=album.id)

        if tag_atts['view']=='gallery':
            return makeGallery(album,images,tag_atts)
        elif tag_atts['view']=='slideshow':
            return makeSlideshow(album,images,tag_atts)
        else:
            context = Context(tag_atts)
            t = Template("""{{ content }}""")
            return t.render(context)
```

The makeGallery and makeSlideshow functions just process the shortcode and its attributes returning a rendered template with all the required HTML like the given else clause but with more complexity (see the github parser examples for ideas).

Everything is working fine but I need to include a custom css file and javascript file for the lightbox in the instance that its a gallery view that has been requested.  At the moment this is included in the main page template file using a custom block but this means that its always there regardless of whether the shortcode exists or a gallery has been requested.

What would be the appropriate method of telling Django to include these additional files from inside the template tag only when required?

I'm loathed to add an additional 'checker' tag that parses the page content in the customcss header block to see whether to include it and again for the customscript block in the footer.

I look forward to hearing from more experience Djangooists.

Chris

Comment: Could you include a short code example of what it is you're doing? I may have some ideas but am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Cheers Cssko,   I have edited and added something more above.

Comment: Sorry I took so long, but could I also see either makeGallery or makeSlideshow? (I'm going to assume they contain roughly the same thing)

Comment: All they do is return the appropriate markup for my gallery or slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use template inheritance, per the [django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) Please note that these are all very generic examples, it should be enough to get you going though. Be sure to check out the docs I linked above.

## base_page.html

```
# pretend your standard html opening stuff is here.

# Put your base css file(s) here. Things you want for every page.
{% block css_block %}
# Leave this empty for now.
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
# If all your pages have the same base layout, put it here.
{% endblock %}

# Put all javascript files here that are needed on all pages.
{% block js_block %}
# Leave this empty for now.
{% endblock %}

#pretend your ending html is here
```

## gallery_template.html

```
{% extends 'base_page.html' %}

{% block css_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery.css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block js_block %}
<script src="gallery.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

## slideshow_template.html

```
{% extends 'base_page.html' %}

{% block css_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block js_block %}
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

## your view functions

```
#camelcase is fine, consistency is important though. 
def make_gallery(album,images,tag_atts) 
    #do things here
    return render_to_response('path/to/gallery_template.html')

def make_slideshow(album,images,tag_atts)
    #do things here
    return render_to_response('path/to/slideshow_template.html')
```

Comment: I was about to scream you legend and then I remembered this is a short tag driven problem.   In my main base.html I have a block called content.   My page model calls the default-page template which extends base.html.   The page content field is placed inside the content block and calls the shorttag tag.   If it finds the album tag then it parses it.  Thus there can be page content before and after the shorttag.   In Wordpress I could have called enque scripts so the scripts were correctly linked at the point of render - I guess I'm looking for a django equal.   Thanks for the response thou.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change up your templates then. What I posted will absolutely work, whatever it is you are doing sounds excessive and clunky.